# Citation cannot contain number?

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

I am generating my paper but my reference cannot show up.

Sample part of the paper:

```
....conductive inks ~\cite{narita1991method} i.e.....
```

I have a `.bib` file and `\bibliography{XXX.bib}` is included.

The log file is giving me this, which I don't understand:

```
Introduction.tex, line 4
Use of \@citex doesn't match its definition.
\reserved@c ->\@tempswafalse \@citex ,
                                      []
l.4 ...his space including conductive inks ~\cite{
                                                  narita1991method} i.e. pai...
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

Anyone familiar with this issue? I am new to LaTeX, this is my first paper so it could be a silly mistake but I can't find what is wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome! Your cite looks fine, and numbers in the citation tag are fine. The mention of numbers in the error-help isn't related (numbers aren't allowed as part of command names). The only way to track it down is by posting a small but complete document, showing the packages that might be causing the trouble, and that other people can test. (The lack of a backslash before `@citex` in the message suggests it happened during font loading somehow.)

Comment: Re. my prev comment: ignore the end; there are backslashes, but they didn't show up in the original question formatting.